# Query Loop Block: possible to restrict just child pages?

Tags: loop, query, block-editor

Is it possible to use the Gutenberg Query Loop block to restrict the output to just the page's children pages?

Or is it necessary to alter the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: It's under Filters, and then you proceed to isolate the parent page.

[image]